How to calibarate SDE parameters with PyTorch model?
I'm building a GRU model for stock price forecasting. I wanted to integrate a stochastic process to the model to model the price volatility.
So, this is the class to produce a stochastic path.
class SDE(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,lam,sigma):
    super().__init__()
    self.lam = lam
    self.sigma = sigma

def forward(self, T, steps, Npaths):
    np.random.seed(4)
    lam = self.lam.detach().numpy()
    sigma= self.sigma.detach().numpy()
     .....
    return sigma * lam * xx

Now, my model is :
class MyModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, args):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.lam = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.0), requires_grad=True)
    self.sigma = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.2), requires_grad=True)
    # GRU layers
    self.gru = nn.GRU(
        self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim, self.layer_dim, batch_first=True, 
                                            dropout=args.dropout, bidirectional=True)

    # SDE 
     levy = SDE(self.lam, self.sigma) 
    # Fully connected layer
    self.fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim * 2, self.output_dim)

def forward(self, x):
        lev = torch.from_numpy(levy(1.0, 16, 1))
        .....
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.args['num_layers']* 2, x.size(0), self.args['n_hidden_units'], 
                                                                                 device=x.device).requires_grad_()
        out, _ = self.gru(x, h0.detach())
        out = out[:, -1, :]
        out = self.fc(out)
        out_m = torch.mul(out, lev)
        return out

The train will besomething like this:
    # Makes predictions
      yhat = self.model(x)
      # Computes loss
      loss = self.loss_fn(y, yhat)
      # Computes gradients
      #loss.requires_grad = True
      loss.backward()
      # Updates parameters and zeroes gradients
      self.optimizer.step()
      self.optimizer.zero_grad()

By training this network, Should this code calibrate and identify optimal values for the sigma and lam parameters used for generating the stochastic path in SDE?
I can see from the debug that their values are always the same.
Any tips, please, to make this code useful for my objective, which is to calibrate the sigma and lam?

You detach the lam and sigma from the computational graph evey step (for convert them to numpy) so they won't receive any gradient feedback. If you want to implement the SDE process, implement them in pure pytorch (atleast the part that interact with lam and sigma)

If you want lam and sigma to be learned, you need to implement them as pytorch Parameters and compute the results of lam and sigma using pytorch methods. When you call .detach().numpy() on values, you remove them from the computational graph, which means pytorch can't update them via backprop.
From your code, you define lam and sigma as Parameters in your MyModel class, so leave that be. For the SDE element, you can replace the class with a function (the SDE class is just holding variables that are already stored in MyModel). The SDE forward method isn't shown, but you need to have that implemented with pytorch methods rather than numpy.
You should also consider what you hope to accomplish with the SDE method. It looks like SDE produces a sequence of values based on lam and sigma that are used to scale the outputs of your GRU. Your model might decide it's easier to avoid the SDE params by setting them to lam=1, sigma=0 or other uninformative parameters.
